# php mysql no longer able to INSERT (Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1 )

Tags: php, mysql, insert, auto-increment

After moving to a new computer (and Mac's Mojave) I have been unable to INSERT rows in the database from php files using classes and objects. Like this:

```
$new_entry = SomeClassName::add_record($foo, $bar );  
if($new_entry && $new_entry->save()) {  
    //do something here  
}
```

The Class definition looks like this:

```
class SomeClassName extends DBObject {
    protected static $table_name="some_table";
    protected static $db_fields = array( 'id' , 'foo' , 'bar' );
    public $id;
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
    public $errors=array();
}
```

`mysqli_error()` gives me:

```
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
```

I have found that things will work as expected if I remove 'id' from the `$db_fields` array and delete the line `public $id;`. 
However, I have dozens of Classes and I dread having to re-edit all of them for this -- especially since all my code worked fine on my old local server (using php5.4) and still works fine on my public server (using php 5.5), but not on my new set-up (using php7).
So my question is: Is there a better solution than the one I came up with? If so what is it?
Advice most welcome and appreciated. (Even ridicule if it helps solve this annoying issue.)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because of a MySQL update (looks like 5.6 to 5.7 to me). You should pass an integer, or `NULL`, instead of an empty string.

Pass `NULL`, or don't mention the field in your query, when the ID is auto incrementing.

If you don't want to explicitly define null for every model, you could try to write some middleware; e.g. `IF field IS id THEN skip field OR use null value` (pseudocode ofc)